# How to pass the value of a variable to another command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pipe

I'm looking to automate file deletion of a certain type via a batch file.
So far, my setup searches for media files, (`.mp3`, `.mp4`), and assigns their file path to a variable, like so:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dir *.mp3 /s /b`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%`
```

The value of `%var%` in this instance would be something like `C:\Users\me\unwanted file.mp3`.

What I'd like to do next is pass the value of the `var` variable to a `del` command, something like:

```
del /f %var%
```

with `C:\Users\me\unwanted file.mp3` being deleted as a result.

Comment: As there is a space in your example value string, you should use `Set "var=%%F"` and `Del /A /F "!var!"` after enabling delayed expansion. However that said, if you're deleting the files, there's no need for all of that, you could delete them directly. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `del /?` to see how to use that command.

Comment: the filename has spaces - quote it: `del /f "%var%"

Comment: Example: `Del /A /F /S /Q *.mp3 *.mp4`. _Please ensure that you try that only in a directory tree containing only files you're willing to erase, as it works rooted in the current directory_.